# Delay popping up a dialog fragment till a webview within has completed loading

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, android-dialogfragment

I have a dialog fragment which essentially contains just a single web view. I want the dialog to popup only once the web view has completed loading the URL.

This is the `onCreateView` of my `DialogFragment`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_A, container, false);

    webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

The problem I have is that the web view object is created only after the `onCreateView()` method is called which will be called only after `show()` is called; which in turn will cause the dialog to popup.

Is there anyway that I can preload the web view before I popup the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a `DialogFragment` because of the `LifeCycle` of the fragment. You want to load the `WebView` prior to showing it to the user. Therefore I would use a CustomLayout with `visibility=GONE` and then when the `WebView` (inside the layout) finishes loading, I'll fade in the layout. Use `FrameLayout` and put it at the top of the hierarchy.

Comment: i am currently using DialogFragment , i want to preload webview in the DialogFragment .when finished loaded, i want to let the DialogFragment show. So how to achieve this?